# styled components + reactstrap how to import bootstrap stylesheet after other stylesheets

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, styled-components

I need to use bootstrap in a few of my projects and one problem I have is that for some reason the bootstrap stylesheet takes priority over the styled component styles.

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.
const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  background: blue;
`;
```

intended result: use the background specifield in my component
actual result: StyledButton has the default bootstrap background

example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/p2wz01wnz7

I'm currently importing bootstrap in my index.js like this:

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

Is there a way I can force it to load last? I'm also using create-react-app just like in the codepen

I do not want to put

```
&&&{
}
```

around all of my styles.

Comment: your sample seems to be working correctly

Comment: try my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55645950/381720

Answer (score 0):

You could place this import statement at the bottom of the header in your html file.  If you have a css or scss import, just put it below that.