# Moving global style sheets above styled-components in <head>

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, gatsby, styled-components

I am currently `import`ing CSS files in one of my components. Those style sheets are added as `link` tags in `<head>`, and will be globally available:

```
import './src/styles/normalize.module.css';
```

I am also using *styled-components*.

Currently, the `link` tags generated by the global CSS `import`s land below the *styled-component* `style` tags, in `<head>`:

[image: Picture of <head>]

I would like the *styled-components* to be **more** specific, i.e. appear **above** the `link` tags from the CSS `import`s.

Is there any way to accomplish that?

*PS: I am using GatsbyJS, but that's probably not relevant to the question.*

Comment: "styled-components to be more specific" — Specificity is determined by the selector on the ruleset, not the position of the stylesheet in the DOM. More specific rules appear later in the cascade. If you wanted the styled component CSS to appear later in the cascade, then you'd need the generated style elements to appear after the link elements, not before them.

Comment: @Quentin Yes. I would like the style sheet <link> to be injected / moved above the <style> added by <styled-components>. Added a picture of the problem, for clarity.

Comment: To be clear, Gatsby's build process adds it in that order automatically. To my knowledge, I do not have control over the order. So I was wondering if someone knew how to change that, via for example some styled-component API or the gatsby-browser.js / gatsby-ssr.js APIs. It is possible to manually add it to html.js, but then the style sheet would have to be static, as opposed to dynamic with a hashed file name.

Comment: I understand you problem with order of styles in `<head>`. But if there will be problem only with `normalize.css` you can use https://github.com/sergeysova/styled-normalize

Answer (score 1):

Gatsby does have a place where you can control the order of tags in the head components, it's [`onPreRenderHTML`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/ssr-apis/#onPreRenderHTML).

However I fiddled with it a bit and it wasn't helpful, as imported css was not extracted during gatsby develop & styled component didn't seem to have attached its style tag in this hook.

There're still 2 things I tried that works, [both described in this docs.](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/creating-global-styles/#add-global-styles-with-css-files-and-no-layout-component)

- import global css to `gatsby-browser.js`. It seems that the imported styles there got picked up first
- let styled-components handle global style via [`createGlobalStyle`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/creating-global-styles/#add-global-styles-with-css-files-and-no-layout-component) (This is not always possible if you use 3rd party css.)

Comment: Hi Derek, thank you for the input. I noticed that when I created a new Gatsby project with only styled-components and a globals CSS imported in gatsby-browser.js, the order was initially correct as you point out. However, after having added layout components, MUI theming, and other packages, the order had swapped. All of a sudden, the link was at the very end. I am not entirely sure why that happens, and I am not sure we can trust that automatic ordering?

Comment: The createGlobalStyle approach does indeed work, but it is a bit inconvenient to have to place all the reset and normalize global CSS into `css\`...\`` tags (I did that, then imported + interpolated it into creatGlobalStyle).

Comment: I should add one more thing. In Gatsby plugins, this type of injection happens in `onRenderBody`. I played around with it and was able to programatically inject the `link` elements into `head`. However, webpack did not resolve the urls in the `link` href, so after it was all built it did not work. I guess using a `style` element in head instead could work, but then you are back to having to write the global CSS inside `css\`...\`` in order to export it.

Comment: @Magnus if you have multiple packages that all inject element into the head tags, it might be worth it to explore `onPreRenderHTML` and try re-ordering the tags there, though `styled-components` injection timing is still a mystery to me, please share if you discover something. It certainly doesn't happen before `onPreRenderHTML`.

Another thing is that the order of plugin being specified _might_ affect the injection order. I don't have a set up to test right now, but it might be worth it to change up the plugin declaration order in `gatsby-config.js` and see if it behaves more consistently

Comment: @Magnus during gatsby build though, it looks like styled-component tag is consistently placed after css import. Do you spot any order different between build & develop?

Comment: Hi Derek. I spent all of yesterday on `onPreRenderHTML`, `onRenderBody`, and other Gatsby browser/ssr APIs,  and I was able to inject tags into head, and move them up and down. It is necessary to first inject it, because if you go through the headComponent in `onPreRenderHTML` you will see that it does not yet contain the CSS files that were imported directly in src components / gatsby-browser.js My problem then became the href path in the link element I injected. Webpack did not resolve the path, so it kept it's static path when landing in the public output folder.

Comment: Later today I will add one plugin / change at the time, and see when the order changes. I have a feeling we cannot trust the cascade though, i.e. how / where the tags are injected in `head`. The ideal scenario would be if we could get a hold of those already resolved link elements in `head` that were added though regular `import`, and sort them to the top. Just to be clear, when  `onPreRenderHTML` runs, `headComponent` does not yet contain the `link` elements for the css files imported in source files.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a layout something like this, try importing your global inside `<App />`

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
   <App />
</ThemeProvider>
```